# Low signal in wifi with Qualcomm QCA61x4A and QCA9377

Tags: drivers, wireless, atheros

I installed Ubuntu in dual boot. My wifi card is Qualcomm QCA61x4A and QCA9377 WiFi and Bluetooth and the signal is very low.

I tried removing and reinstalling firmware but it didn't help.

The signal is high when I'm only 1 metre away from the router.

In Windows 10 which I run in dual boot, in Microsoft default driver it shows low signal but after installing the driver from Dell this problem is fixed.

Can I install the Windows driver in Ubuntu?

Or is there any other fix?

Comment: i tried still low signal

Comment: For me card is working but range is ver lesss

Comment: You can install windows wifi driver with `sudo apt install ndiswrapper`. This little program is able to install windows network driver. But it doesn't work with exe files. You need the `.inf` file, which is the driver. Just extract the exe file and there you have the `.inf` file.

Comment: I installed but it is not using the windows driver it uses the old driver from linux i even added in blacklist then also it uses linux

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of the terminal command `lspci -nnk | awk -v n='[0280]' 'p&&/^\S/{p=0}!p{p=index($0,n)}p'`? Thanks.